# Can't get custom header with $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, angularjs-http

I'm trying to get the header with `$http`, I send a response with the data and header with Node.js, x-auth is my custom header.
I can get the `response.data` just fine,
but when I use `response.header('x-auth')` it prints `null`.
When I test the response with 'Postman' everything works properly and I get the header as expected.
I can even see the custom header in the dev tools,

this is the cors of my nodejs cors code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/test'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.headers('x-auth'));

}, function errorCallback(response) {

    console.log("error");
});
```

hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see if the header is actually there

Comment: I checked and it's there, so why it's null?

Comment: Is actual header name all lower case as shown?

Comment: Yes it is, only lower case

Comment: In case you are performing a CORS-Request, you will need to expose the headers by adding `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ...` at the server.

Comment: ok, I editing my question to show the cors of my server

Comment: @PerfectPixel thank you it works now

Comment: @PerfectPixel please post the tip/solution as an answer :)